# How can I get both elements and their indices from a list based on a condition?

Tags: python, list, filtering, enumeration

I have a list that has duplicate values, I have found out the lists of maximum length but I would like to get the indices of these maximum lists and add them to my index list.

```
mylist = [{'destination', 'graph'}, {'vertex'}, {'destination', 'modify'}, {'destination', 'modify'}, {'modify', 'return'}, {'destination'}]

max_len = len(sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)[0])
uniq_list = [k for k in mylist if len(k) == max_len]
print(uniq_list)
```

Current output:

```
[{'destination', 'graph'}, {'destination', 'modify'}, {'destination', 'modify'}, {'modify', 'return'}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{'destination', 'graph'}, {'destination', 'modify'}, {'destination', 'modify'}, {'modify', 'return'}]
```

```
index_list = [0,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Btw, you can get `max_len` much easier as `max(map(len, mylist))`

Comment: @Georgy Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) to keep both the sublists and index in tuples, and unpack them with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
out = ((ix, k) for ix, k in enumerate(mylist) if len(k) == max_len)
index_list , uniq_list = zip(*out)

print(index_list)
# (0, 2, 3, 4)

print(uniq_list)
#({'graph', 'destination'}, {'modify', 'destination'}, 
# {'modify', 'destination'}, {'modify', 'return'})
```